# lookup function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here I have a table contains some product price info in every month, I'm going to lookup the price for a specific SKU by month.

Because some of the SKU may have **no price** in specific month (like cell `I8` in the picture), in this situation, I will let the cell return **last non blank value** in the row.

Here's the problem, If a row doesn't contains blank value, the formula I used would not be able to return the **exact value** that I'm looking for.

[image]

Formula that I used to return last non blank value:

```
=LET(fRow,XLOOKUP(A2,A8:A17,C8:N17),XLOOKUP(TRUE,fRow<>"",fRow,,0,-1))
```

In the image example, I prefer the cell `D2` return value of `1700` if no blank value in the row.

Sorry for my poor English, I hope you guys can understand what I'm asking for and give me a hand, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is a good start. I believe you need to update your first `xlookup` to only return the partial row instead of the whole row. So you need to figure out how to incorporate `D1` in your return array.

Having said that here is how I would go about doing what I just stated:

1. reformat data in D1 so that it matches your months found in C7 to N7
2. instead of using xlookup in the first section of your formula I used index/match:

`INDEX($C$8:$C$17,MATCH(A3,$A$8:$A$17)):INDEX($C$8:$N$17,MATCH(A3,$A$8:$A$17),MATCH($B$1,$C$7:$N$7))`

Instead of explaining this formula I will refer you to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187863/can-excels-index-function-return-array

When I substituted the above into your formula it worked:

`=LET(fRow,INDEX($C$8:$C$17,MATCH(A3,$A$8:$A$17)):INDEX($C$8:$N$17,MATCH(A3,$A$8:$A$17),MATCH($B$1,$C$7:$N$7)),XLOOKUP(TRUE,fRow<>"",fRow,,0,-1))`

Answer (score 0):

Returns `0` for both `0` and empty values

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(
       FILTER(A7:N17, INDEX(A7:N17,,1)=A2),
       XMATCH(F1, A7:N7, 0)),"")
```

Returns `""` for empty values

```
=IFERROR(
   IF(LEN(
      INDEX(
        FILTER(A7:N17, INDEX(A7:N17,,1)=A2),
        XMATCH(F1, A7:N7, 0))),
      INDEX(
        FILTER(A7:N17, INDEX(A7:N17,,1)=A2),
        XMATCH(F1, A7:N7, 0)),""),"")
```

Same formula with LET:

```
=LET(
     range,A7:N17, month,F1, sku,A2,
     result, INDEX(
        FILTER(range, INDEX(range,,1)=sku),
        MATCH(month, CHOOSEROWS(range, 1), 0)),
     IF(LEN(result), result, ""))
```